# Node.js/child_process：кракозябры при попытке вывести console.log(stderr) в коллбэке метода exec

Tags: node.js

Мне нужно программно запустить Electron.js-приложение. В Node.js вроде как для таких вещей вроде есть [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback).

```
import ChildProcess, {ChildProcess as ChildProcess__type, ExecException} from 'child_process';

const childProcess: ChildProcess__type = ChildProcess.exec(
        'electron ProjectInitializer__ElectronMain.js',
        { cwd: __dirname },
        (error: ExecException | null, stdout: string | Buffer, stderr: string | Buffer) => {
          if (error) {
            console.log('----');
            console.log(stderr);
          }
        }
    );
```

При попытке запустить приложение таким образом возникает ошибка, а `console.log(stderr);` отображает кракозябры, которые ничем, из того что я пробовал, не декодируются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кстати говоря, та же самая команда `electron ProjectInitializer__ElectronMain.js` прекрасно программно запускается с помощью [execa](https://github.com/sindresorhus/execa) - библиотеки, позиционируемой как улучшенный `child-process`.

```
import executeExternalCommand, { ExecaReturnValue } from 'execa';

try {
  await executeExternalCommand(
      'electron',
      ['ProjectInitializer__ElectronMain.js'],
      { cwd: __dirname }
  );
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

К сожалению, ввиду того, что информации по этой библиотеке меньше, чем о нативном `child-process`, я не могу найти решения таких типичных проблем, как вывод в консоль данных из дочернего процесса или передача данных в дочерний процесс ([связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/991604/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-node-js-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%B8)).

Полагаю, решение данной проблемы следует начать с того, чтобы сообщение об ошибке выводилось в читаемом виде. Где нужно настроить кодировку? (Кракозябры выводятся во всех консолях, которые при запуске других программ прекрасно отображают текст - и латиницу, и кириллицу, и азиатские языки).